# Storing SegmentedControl Segment State in NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to store the Segment Index of a `SegmentedControl` in `NSUserDefaults`.

Here is the code for loading the preferences and the preferences 'SAVE' button.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Get the stored data before the view loads
   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

   int yPrefSegment = [defaults integerForKey:@"yPref"];

   prefYsegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = yPrefSegment;

}

- (IBAction)savePrefButton:(id)sender
{

   int yPref = [[prefYsegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex] integerValue];

   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   [defaults synchronize];

   NSLog(@"Data saved");
}
```

I am getting an error on the line (in the `savePrefButton`) :

```
int yPref = [[prefYsegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex] integerValue];
```

Error is:  `Expected Identifier`

I am lost here. Don't know what it is talking about.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one syntax error and two semantical errors.

The syntax error:

```
[prefYsegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex]
```

Choose one of the method call or dot notation for accessing properties. Use either

```
[prefYsegmentedControl selectedSegmentIndex]
```

or

```
prefYsegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex
```

The first semantical error:

```
prefYsegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex
```

is already an integer. No need to call `integerValue` on it. (You can't send messages to primitive types anyway. This is not Smalltalk.)

The second semantical error: you don't actually store the index in `NSUserDefaults`. Insert

```
[defaults setInteger:yPref forKey:@"yPref"];
```

before you synchronize the user defaults.

Comment: Thanks H2CO3 and ashevin. You both answered my question in different ways. This is working.

Answer (score 0):

You are treating the property as if it were an object.  It's not.  Just use

```
int yPref = prefYSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
```